# Getting facebook reactions counts on profile or group feed call

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

It's possible to retrieve total reactions counts for each type of reactions like *haha, wow...* in one call using facebook graph api for page feed call. In the graph api calling URL we can include those reaction fields with AS variable.As a example -

> page_id/feed?fields=message,picture....,reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_love),reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_wow)....

But it's not possible to get those all reactions counts on profile / group feed endpoint in one call.
**Also these endpoints don't support AS variable.**

I saw [this facebook bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1911644599096974/) was assigned regarding this issue and facebook developers replied that it's not possible for profile and group feed endpoints.

So how do I retrieve each of those reaction counts per post in one graph api call for profile and group feed call. It works well with page feed call. Suggest me better alternatives too with examples or links at least if i can't with one call. But in what ways i can achieve my goal and avoid too many calls when i am displaying group/profile feed posts in a website along with all those reactions counts per post?.

I hope i explained with details about what i want and it's not a duplicate post.

Comment: what is your current api call?

Comment: For any post you can retrieve the total counts of different reactions by this:
 
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/post_id?fields=reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(1).as(like),reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(1).as(wow),reactions.type(SAD).limit(0).summary(1).as(sad)

Comment: @ssakash I see error when I paste ur URL, I expected feed/posts endpoints not post_id

Comment: @luschn i updated the question to include a url i used for page feed call but it don't work with group/profile feed call.

Comment: Hi any fb Developer here?? Just tell me how do I get all those reactions counts by least calls on graph api feed endpoint? It is not right to get all posts by one call and get all reaction counts per post by something like many successive calls per display of feed

Comment: Look like i have to call 6 times to get all kinds of reactions counts per post. This is going to be a mess in terms of various calls and checks. I hope FB should allow getting reactions for group/profile feed endpoint like page.

Comment: can anybody at least show me how to write graph api url with batch request which i will call within my javascript ajax?